# Response.AsJson doen't work when calling it from a function in NancyFx

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, extension-methods, anonymous-types, nancy

The extension methods:

```
Response.AsJson
Response.AsXml
```

works fine when calling it from the constractor like:

```
public class TweetModule : NancyModule
    {
     public TweetModule()
            : base("/")
        {

            Post["/{action}.json/"] = parameters =>
            {
               return Reponse.Asjson(new {output:parameters.action}); // OK
            }
        }
     }
```

But when I call it from a function like this:

```
public class TweetModule : NancyModule
    {
     public TweetModule()
            : base("/")
        {

            Post["/{action}.{format}/"] = parameters =>
            {
               return GetResponse( parameters.action,parameters.format); // Error
            }
        }

        public Response GetResponse(string action,string format)
        {
           if (format == "json")
            return Response.AsJson(new {output:action}); // error
          else
            return Response.AsXml(new {output:action}); // error
        }


     }
```

I get this exception:

> <>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String] cannot be serialized because it
>   does not have a parameterless constructor.

any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na that works just fine. The problem is that your captured parameter is called **{fortmat}** and you then pass along **parameters.format** which is never captured due to the typo

And I have to point out that your code won't even compile since **function** is not a valid keyword in C#, I just assumed that you actual meant it to say **public** instead.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried it on my machine last night and it worked (using the 0.10 nugets of Nancy). What values are you passing in to get the error? Also are you running on the ASP.NET host?

Comment: By the way, you should remove the :base("/") call, that's implicit as default.